# Can't unlock Macbook after sleep until powering off and on

Tags: login

The problem occurs after closing the lid of the laptop and it goes to sleep. When I open the lid, I am prompted for the password for my user as usual. When I press enter, there is no reaction.

Now the only action I can do that gets a reaction is to push the power button twice to turn the screen off and then on. At this point, I am again able to enter the password, but this time when I push enter the masked password gets selected (the field doesn't shake). Same results for correct or incorrect passwords. Pushing the cancel or switch user button has no effect.

To log in again I cycle the power off and on. The problem recurs sometimes often (many times a day) and infrequently at other times.

I couldn't identify anything interesting in the logs; this is the leadup to me cycling the power in the system.log:

```
Apr 11 18:00:27 dresnick-mbp kernel[0]: kauth external resolver timed out (1 timeout(s) of 60 seconds).
Apr 11 18:00:31 dresnick-mbp.local identityservicesd[500]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7f8153215230>: notification observer: com.apple.iChat   notification: __CFNotification 0x7f8151611240 {name = _NSDoNotDisturbEnabledNotification}
Apr 11 18:00:32 dresnick-mbp.local WindowServer[132]: CGError post_notification(const CGSNotificationType, void *const, const size_t, const bool, const CGSRealTimeDelta, const int, const CGSConnectionID *const, const pid_t): Timed out 1.000 second wait for reply from "Firefox" for synchronous notification type 102 (kCGSDisplayWillSleep) (CID 0xa56b, PID 804)
Apr 11 18:00:32 dresnick-mbp.local WindowServer[132]: CGError post_notification(const CGSNotificationType, void *const, const size_t, const bool, const CGSRealTimeDelta, const int, const CGSConnectionID *const, const pid_t): Timed out 1.000 second wait for reply from "Microsoft Outlook" for synchronous notification type 102 (kCGSDisplayWillSleep) (CID 0xfa03, PID 465)
Apr 11 18:00:32 dresnick-mbp.local WindowServer[132]: CGError post_notification(const CGSNotificationType, void *const, const size_t, const bool, const CGSRealTimeDelta, const int, const CGSConnectionID *const, const pid_t): Timed out 1.000 second wait for reply from "Microsoft Lync" for synchronous notification type 102 (kCGSDisplayWillSleep) (CID 0x59a3, PID 477)
Apr 11 18:00:32 dresnick-mbp.local WindowServer[132]: device_generate_desktop_screenshot: authw 0x7f91f48773e0(2004), shield 0x7f91ed304810(2001)
Apr 11 18:00:32 dresnick-mbp.local WindowServer[132]: device_generate_lock_screen_screenshot: authw 0x7f91f48773e0(2004)[0, 0, 1440, 900] shield 0x7f91ed304810(2001), dev [1440,900]
Apr 11 18:00:42 dresnick-mbp.local loginwindow[74]: ERROR | -[LWBuiltInScreenLockAuthLion askForPasswordBuiltIn:] | Attempted to add an observer when already observing
Apr 11 18:00:42 dresnick-mbp.local WindowServer[132]: CGXDisplayDidWakeNotification [13749210101618]: posting kCGSDisplayDidWake
Apr 11 18:00:42 dresnick-mbp.local WindowServer[132]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: Deferring.
Apr 11 18:00:46 dresnick-mbp.local identityservicesd[500]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7f8153215230>:    NC Disabled: NO
```

I'm running a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014), OS X 10.10.2

Comment: I have the exact same behavior and it just started happening a couple of days ago. I also looked through the console logs and the only interesting thing I found were a bunch of these: 4/15/15 15:45:08.522 identityservicesd[814]: [Warning] Response identities is not what we expected ((null) instead of NSArray) (null), error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1001.)", resultCode 20000 Anyone have ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: I don't have those errors in the log, I'm not sure they are related.

Comment: i have a user with the same issue. he's offsite, so i can't get more info.
any other ideas besides crashing it?
the machine is brand new from yesterday. 10.10.3 macbook pro 15"

Comment: I only close and open my macbook when I'm at home, so it may have something to do with not having access to the corporate network/LDAP servers. I've started waiting a few seconds after opening the macbook before attempting to log in (to ensure that wifi is available) and haven't had the problem in a while.

Comment: @DavidResnick has that solution been holding for you?  I'm experiencing the same behavior in the same situation.

Comment: @drewchristianson I've since switched laptops and haven't encountered the problem on the new one at all. I believe that the problem recurred very few times on the old one too. Bummer that there is no real solution this yet!

Comment: Same issue on 2015 MBP Retina with 10.11.3. After entering the password, no reaction. But if I wait like 2-3 minutes, password box shakes as if wrong password. Tried shutdown, asking for user name and password in separate popup window, tried all usernames and passwords with and without admin rights, it says not valid. My laptop is corporate provided, LDAP configured as well. And it occurs when at home. Sometimes login screen says network accounts unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

This was happening to me as well with very similar error message. When I saw it was saying it couldn't find a display I tried plugging in an external display.. sure enough it turned on. I think this happens if the screen goes to sleep while plugged into an external display. Pretty awful bug. Note that I am testing it by plugging in the identical display.. not sure if another display would fix it.